# Philosophically is it true to number them like this?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Although there are three apples, it could be 'there are two apples,' or 'there is one apple,' or 'there is no apple'? I mean it's not general but philosophical, isn't it? I'm sorry to repeat the same question, but I confirm that it is ***philosophically***.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Philosophical has nothing to do with numbering apples.

Comment: This seems to be a question about philosophy, not learning English.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is **technically**.  It is **technically** true that when there are three apples, the statement "there are two apples" is true (even though the average person wouldn't say that).  Note that the statement "there are no apples" is not true at all when there are three apples.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee Could you make an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean "technically" and not "philosophically"

In any statement "there are three apples" there is an underlying assumption. It may mean "there are three apples (on the table now)" or "There are three apples (in the universe)" and so on. The meaning is ambiguous and relies on context and general knowledge to be understood.

If there are three apples in the universe.  But there are two apples on the table in front of you. Then you could say "There are two apples". It is technically correct.

If there are three apples on the table, but for some reason you feel that two of them are separate from the other you could say "there are two apples" with the implication "There are two apples (here, and one more, over there)".

If someone asks "Are there two apples" and there are three apples on the table, you can reply "yes" on the basis that "There are two apples (that you need and one left over)

But if you have three apples on the table and you want to tell someone the number of apples on the table then it is a lie to say "there are two apples".

It is a lie.  In a court and under oath you would be committing a crime if you said "I saw two men" when in fact you saw three men. It is not the whole truth.

It is *not* technically true that "there are no apples". Under any circumstances.  This is equivalent (in English) to the "There aren't any apples".

I think I've covered all bases.  In most contexts it is a lie to say "there are two apples" when there are three.